# Resolving method calls from generic object in enhanced for loop

Tags: java, generics

This is more than likely a simple question for someone who is more familiar with Java than I am. Here's the gist of my issue:

I have a function that basically generates the possible combinations of the objects contained within an `ArrayList`. Being that I have multiple objects that need to use this function, the function is screaming at me to be made generic. The issue I'm encountering, though, is that an enhanced for-loop is unable to resolve method calls from the generic iterator. I understand why this happening, but I'm not familiar enough with Java to know how to resolve this issue. In any case, here is my code:

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> determineIdealOrderCombination(ArrayList<T> orders, int position){
            // Local Variable Declarations
                List<ArrayList<T>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
                int k = orders.size()+1;         // Add one due to the do-while loop
                int theoreticalQuantity;
                int indexOfMaxProfit;
                double maxProfit;
                int[] s;             // Here we'll keep indices pointing to elements in input array
                double[] profits;    // Here we'll keep track of the profit of each combination

            // Begin searching for valid combinations
                do {
                    // Setup
                        k--;
                        s = new int[k];
                        profits = new double[k];

                    // Generate combinations
                        if ( (k <= orders.size()) && (k > 0) ) {
                            // Set the first index sequence: 0, 1, 2,...
                            for (int i = 0; (s[i] = i) < k - 1; i++) ;
                            subsets.add(getSubset(orders, s));
                            for (; ; ) {
                                int i;
                                // Find position of item that can be incremented
                                for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && s[i] == orders.size() - k + i; i--) ;
                                if (i < 0) {
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    s[i]++;                    // increment this item
                                    for (++i; i < k; i++) {    // fill up remaining items
                                        s[i] = s[i - 1] + 1;
                                    }
                                    subsets.add(getSubset(orders, s));
                                }
                            }

                            // All combinations have been evaluated, now throw away invalid combinations that violate the upper limit
                            // and calculate the valid combinations profits.
                                for (int i = 0; i < subsets.size(); i++) {
                                    // Calculate the final position
                                        theoreticalQuantity = position;
                                        profits[i] = 0;
                                        for (T t : subsets.get(i)) {
                                            theoreticalQuantity += t.getQuantity(); // <-- THE PROBLEM
                                            profits[i] += calculateProjectedProfit(t.getSecurity(), t.getQuantity(), t.getPrice()); // <-- THE PROBLEM
                                        }

                                        if(theoreticalQuantity > _MAX_POSITION_PER_ASSET){
                                            // Negate profits if final position violates the position limit on an asset
                                                profits[i] = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        else{
                            break;
                        }
                }
                while( (subsets.size() == 0)  );

                // Verify that the subset array is not zero - it should never be zero
                    if(subsets.size() == 0){
                        return new ArrayList<>();
                    }

                // Return the most profitable combination, if any.
                    indexOfMaxProfit = -1;
                    maxProfit = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                    for(int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++){
                        if(profits[i] != Double.MIN_VALUE){
                            if(profits[i] > maxProfit){
                                maxProfit = profits[i];
                                indexOfMaxProfit = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if( (maxProfit > 0) && (indexOfMaxProfit != -1) ){
                        return subsets.get(indexOfMaxProfit);
                    }
                    else{
                        return new ArrayList<>();
                    }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know `T` will have the method `getQuantity()`? Or any other method not in `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: @bcsb1001 Yep, that's the catch and the reason the error is being thrown at me. I, as the author, know that this function will only be used by objects that will have this method but the compiler doesn't know this to be fact.

Comment: Looks like you need to create an interface with those methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you tell the compiler that the incoming objects have the relevant methods:

```
public interface MyCommonInterface {
  public int getQuantity();
}

private <T extends MyCommonInterface> ArrayList<T> determineIdealOrderCombination(ArrayList<T> orders, int position) {
```

As an additional note, i would read some tutorials on generics before attempting to use them.  they are a little tricky to get the hang of initially.  however, once you put out a little effort to learn the basics, you should be in a much better place to actually utilize them.

Comment: There are also other methods - `getSecurity()` and `getPrice()`. But this is indeed the correct approach, probably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Forgive me for my ignorance here, but does the interface need to encapsulate my class that defines these methods, or is it a separate entity?

Comment: @Mlagma - that's entirely up to you and the best design for your program.  it could be that all your objects extend a common base class, or they implement a common interface.  either way works.